# How do I trigger an href with a unique identified?

Tags: jquery, href

I'm trying to trigger an `href` with a unique identifier `data-currencycode`. I can find how to do it with a class or if but not a unique identifier.

```
<ul class="currency_switcher">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" data-currencycode="USD">USD</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="reset default" data-currencycode="GBP">GBP</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="active" data-currencycode="EUR">EUR</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" data-currencycode="AUD">AUD</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" data-currencycode="CAD">CAD</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="" data-currencycode="NZD">NZD</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How would I trigger `currencycode="USD"` for example?

Comment: define trigger? Trigger a click event on the anchor? How is this event established?

Comment: What does _trigger a href_ mean?

Comment: You really should reformat that html. Not everyone is fortunate to have a monitor that's 5 miles wide.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("a[data-currencycode=USD]").trigger("click");
```

See the [jQuery Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: For broader terms, you may want to add how to check for a data attribute value for a `$("a").on("click"...` event, where it's not in the selector.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with this question.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for answering the question to quickly. After some research it certainly looks like the right answer but unfortunately it looks like javascript is unable to select a link in this way. I will find another way around it. Thanks again though!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you trigger a link with `href="#"`? It should run whatever handler you've defined with `$("a").click(function(){...})`

Comment: It won't follow the link, but since there's no URL in the `href` what does that matter?